# When reading strings from a .txt file '\n' is automatically placed after string. Can I remove this?

Tags: python

When I get my final output the strings have a `\n` added on to to the end. Is there a way I can remove this, or is it just part of the readlines() function? The program itself take strings typed in by the user, saves them to a file,  then reads the file to display the strings that were input. Everything is working, I just can't seem to get rid of the extra characters that are added on in the final answer.

```
def readstring(f, line):
    string = line.strip('\r\n')
    return string

def writestring(f, string):
    f.write('\n' + string)

num_lines1 = sum(1 for line in open('string.txt'))

with open("string.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    cont = "Y"
    while cont.upper() == "Y":
        d = input("Enter input or, enter q to exit loop:")
        g = 0
        if d != "q":
            string = d
            writestring(f, string)
            h = g + 1
        else:
            print("saving.....")
            break

    f.seek(0)

    for line in f:
        print(readstring(f,line))

num_lines2 = sum(1 for line in open('string.txt'))

r = num_lines2 - num_lines1
print(r)

f.close()

with open("string.txt", "r",) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[num_lines1:num_lines2]
    print(lines)

f.close()
```

Comment: You do realize that a file consisting of strings separated by `'\n'` is read line by line as a bunch of strings with `'\n'` at the end, right?

Comment: Also note that you are printing `lines`, a list, instead of each line in `lines`, which are strings, so you're seeing each line's `repr` instead of its `str`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - your're right. That's why I deleted my comment (before I read your ones).

Comment: Can you clarify what trailing newline you're talking about, and if you're referring to the result of printing a list? As your question stands, it's likely that you have a misunderstanding of what data you're looking at and none of the current answers are appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rstrip()` method on the strings to remove the newline.

```
lines = [l.rstrip('\n') for l in f.readlines()[num_lines1:num_lines2]]
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't understand keepends in reference to a file readlines().  For a streamreader I get it.  Is there an easy/efficient way to cast the file open into a StreamReader?

Comment: Thank you guys. I  figured I could use something like l.rstrip, I just wasn't sure if there was another better way. Thanks again for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ending newline while **reading line by line** or call rstrip to remove ending newline for each items in "lines" list.

```
lines = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), f.readlines()[num_lines1:num_lines2])
```

A trailing newline character is kept in the string

```
def readline(self, length=None):
    r"""
    A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent
    when a file ends with an incomplete line). ...
    """
    ...
    i = self.buf.find('\n', self.pos)
    ...

def readlines(self, sizehint = 0):
    ...
    line = self.readline()
    ...
```

Comment: The question says there's a trailing newline and asks how to remove it. This answer says that there's a trailing newline and you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TigerhawkT3

Comment: You can replace `lambda x: x.rstrip()` with simply `str.rstrip`, but, more importantly, the result will print `<map object at...>` instead of useful content in Python 3, which is likely what's being used here.

Comment: Thanks. @TigerhawkT3